# 15 de diciembre 2015: Se abre Stack Overflow en español al público

Tags: discusión, fase-beta

Mañana 15 de diciembre el sitio cambiará a la versión Beta Pública. Esto quiere decir que todos podrán registrarse y ser miembros de la mejor comunidad para desarrolladores de habla hispana.

Los únicos cambios que deben esperar son mínimos. Todo permanecerá relativamente igual con excepción de ver más gente aquí.  Quiero pedirles que inviten a todos sus amigos, colegas, etc.  ¡Llenemos el sitio mañana!

Les recuerdo que todos los temas de interés para nosotros, los desarrolladores, se aceptarán aquí.  Vamos a formar nuestra propia voz y ámbito.  Aunque somos Stack Overflow, no somos ni seremos la misma comunidad, pues nuestras culturas y necesidades son diferentes.  Formemos nuestra comunidad propia.  Esto lo podremos llevar a cabo si damos la oportunidad de que los miembros pregunten sobre lo que les interesa.

Quiero también avisarles de que nuestro beta público no será un beta tradicional.  Nuestra comunidad no se cerrará. Otras comunidades propuestas en Area51 deben probar que pueden atraer a gente y mantenerla interesada.  Nosotros no tenemos que demostrar nada.  Enfoquémonos en crear nuestra comunidad y no en las estadísticas que otros sitios necesitan para no ser cerrados.

**Mañana es un día muy importante, así que a dormir temprano y a desayunar bien.**

Comment: Y a conseguir muchos sombreros.

Comment: Siiiii!!!! Yupii.

Comment: ¡Wooow! Vaya que es una excelente noticia y pues... a compartir  .

Comment: ¡que buena noticia! ¡excelente!

Comment: ¡Excelente! A darle con ganas

Comment: Excelente noticia! ce bine spaniola ma bucur! =)

Comment: Gran día, creo que se debe hacer una mención especial a Juan Antonio Castillo, http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/21/jachguate que a pesar de todo, volvió a insistir con la propuesta que ahora es toda una realidad.

Comment: ¿a qué hora y En qué huso horario?

Comment: Estoy tratando de entrar directamente a http://es.stackoverflow.com directamente, y sigue mostrando el mensaje de que el sitio está en beta privada... ¿Hay algún problema? ¿Será hasta las 00:00 (UTC) del 16 de diciembre?

Comment: ¡Estamos ya en el beta público!

Comment: Excelente noticia. Aunque no debemos preocuparnos por las estadísticas, tal como lo hice ver en diferentes debates en Area51, para es.StackOverflow, las estadísticas se darán solas!

Auguro el mayor de los éxitos a este sitio y me encanta verlo finalmente aquí. Gracias a todos los que han apoyado la iniciativa.