# Se deberían quitar preguntas antiguas donde no se cumple los requisitos de una pregunta

Tags: discusión, eliminación-de-preguntas

Resulta que a veces me encuentro ***[preguntas antiguas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-un-inner-y-un-outer-join)*** la cual es vieja y en la cual no se ve ni el mas mínimo esfuerzo.

Aparte esta pregunta se basa en opiniones y tiene varias preguntas ***`¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un inner y un outer join? Y ¿cuál es la función de los modificadores?`***

Yo no se vosotros pero yo creo que este tipo de preguntas deberían ser modificadas o eliminadas.

Comment: en serio queres eliminar una pregunta con 129 votos a favor? y con una respuesta que llega casi a 200?? me gustaria saber el motivo... Te comento que algunas preguntas estan por motivos historicos, otras se hicieron durante la beta cerrada, y los estandares de las preguntas se fueron construyendo con el tiempo. No todas las preguntas de la beta o los primeros tiempos cumplen con los estandares... pero no por eso, las vamos a eliminar... muchas sirven por cuestiones historicas....

Comment: Pero se puede modificar de alguna manera no para que se cumplan los estandares @gbianchi

Comment: que le modificarias a esa pregunta, que es directa, no se le puede agregar codigo, y no cumpliria nunca con ninguno de los estandares actuales? tene en cuenta que para que el sitio arrancara, no solo se necesitaba gente, si no preguntas para generar trafico...

Comment: vale muchas gracias @gbianchi

Comment: 1. Hay preguntas "pobres", "pésimas" y varios etcétera, pero con respuestas excelentes. 2. Me intriga un poco (mucho) que dieras como ejemplo a eliminar una pregunta a la cual también respondiste. 3. Como te mencionan, muchas preguntas se mantienen por cuestiones históricas; además, la pregunta a la que hacés referencia es de noviembre de 2015, y [es.so] pasó a beta público en diciembre del mismo año.

Comment: Hay un punto importante que hay que señalar en este caso, la pregunta fue respondida por el mismo autor, así que asumiría que la escribió @jachguate para responderla el mismo, por lo que en este caso podemos ser más flexibles en lo de "mostrar lo que investigaste" ya que esto es justamente la respuesta.

Comment: A veces parece que perdemos el norte y olvidamos el motivo por el cual existe esta plataforma, que no es otro que compartir conocimiento. Que las reglas no nos impidan ver el bosque.

Comment: @fedorqui tienes todas las razon del mundo   gracias por abrirmes los ojos, a lo mejor SOes debería volver a permitir éste tipo de preguntas de nuevo

Comment: @gbianchi ya que se la opinión de mi pregunta me recomienda eliminarla o dejarla?

Comment: Eso es meta.. no es necesario eliminar nada...

Comment: Vale muchas gracias @gbianchi

Comment: @JavierG.Raya si quieres eliminar esa pregunta, entonces para que la respondiste, me parece contradictorio de tu parte, por otra parte esa pregunta tiene muchisimos votos al igual que las respuestas que recibio,

Comment: ya porque no me leí las normas y no sabias que antes se permitían ese tipo de preguntas

Comment: pero ya esta aclarado @Japv :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se deben **eliminar** preguntas sólo por ser antiguas y que si se preguntaran el día de hoy seguramente serían cerradas.

En primer lugar, no se elimina contenido que corresponda a la temática del sitio que cumpla con los requisitos de participación (puede ser mediante votos, respuestas y comentarios) , si acaso, analizando caso por caso, las preguntas antiguas que no cumplan con los requisitos actuales podrían cerrarse si el dejar la pregunta abierta causara algún tipo de problema.

En segundo lugar, el esfuerzo que se espera es de *buscar **en el sitio** antes de publicar una pregunta*. El caso referido como ejemplo es la pregunta número 36 eso nos da una idea de que muy difílmente habría preguntas sobre lo mismo  en el momento en el que se publicó, más concretamente, en aquel momento (la pregunta fue publicada durante el beta privado) lo que se requería eran preguntas que sirvieran primero como ejemplos de contenido dentro y fuera de la temática del sitio.

Relacionado

- [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/65)

Referencias

- [15 de diciembre 2015: Se abre Stack Overflow en español al público](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258/65)